# How to get response of Python Script in Sencha Touch?

Tags: ajax, python-2.7, sencha-touch-2.1

I have written a Python script named abc.py which prints a json array. The code is given below

```
import urllib2
import json
json_object={"key":"value"}
print json_object
```

The output is as follows:

```
{'key': 'value'}
```

Now I want to retrive this json in my Sencha Touch Application. I am making an ajax Call. The code is written below:

```
  Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: 'resources/startup/abc.py',
    contentType: 'application/json',
     reader:
            {
                type: 'json',

            },
    success: function(response) {

        console.log(response);

    },

    }
});
```

But when I am running my application, I am not getting the json object. Instead I am getting the raw code written inside abc.py.

Output:

```
import urllib2
import json
json_object={"key":"value"}
print json_object
```

Where I am doing a mistake??? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score -4):

this is a python bug.
rename abc.py with another filename.

Comment: This seems very unlikely, please list a source for your answer.

Comment: how can this bug be related to renaming the file..? strange !

Comment: Do not use the name "abc.py" for your python source file. If you are not convinced, create a temporary folder, create a file "abc.py" and write a hello world inside. Then, use that temporary folder as current path and try to launch the python interactive interpreter. Strangely, python traps with an error. Tested with python 2.7 and 3.2 (linux).

Comment: That works absolutely fine:
mkdir tmp && cd tmp && echo "print 'Hello, world'" > abc.py && python abc.py && echo $?
Hello, world
0

Comment: Then sorry, I was wrong. Here is my output (I only run a python console): mkdir tmp && cd tmp && echo "print 'Hello, world'" > abc.py && python
Hello, world
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 68, in <module>
    import os
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 398, in <module>
    import UserDict
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/UserDict.py", line 83, in <module>
    import _abcoll
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/_abcoll.py", line 11, in <module>
    from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod
ImportError: cannot import name ABCMeta